# What is the purpose of using .map(.range(1)) together? range always returns [0]?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

Simple question on this output
    var newVal = _.range(1);
    console.log(newVal);
    //[0]

```
var STARTING_NUMBER = 1;
var _names = ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipisicing", "elit"];

var _bgcolors = ["#FC9D9A", "#F9CDAD", "#C8C8A9"];
var _colors = ["#FE4365", "#83AF9B"]
var _generateItem = function(){
  return {
    id: Math.random(),
    name: _.sample(_names),
    bgcolor: _.sample(_bgcolors),
    color: _.sample(_colors),
    opacity: new Transitionable(0),
    transX: new Transitionable(-_width)
  }
}
//why is _.range needed? why just make STARTING_NUMBER = [0];
$scope.items = _.map(_.range(STARTING_NUMBER), function(){
      return _generateItem();
    })


setInterval(function(){
  $scope.add();
  if(!$scope.$$phase)
    $scope.$apply();
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Even better... why not just `$scope.items = [_generateItem()]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is being done to keep the logic generic.
What the code is trying to do is to generate some items ( which are functions returning values ) and store them in an array of length STARTING_NUMBER .
So your assumption is true if STARTING_NUMBER has only 1 value i.e. 1 ,
but here it can be kept dynamic i.e. 1 or 2 or 10 .... , and $scope.items array will be an array generated equal to that length .

Here is a demo using changed value with STARTING_NUMBER = 10  ( dependencies commented out )

**demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/m02h0n3g/1/

```
var $scope = {};
var STARTING_NUMBER = 10;
var _names = ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipisicing", "elit"];

var _bgcolors = ["#FC9D9A", "#F9CDAD", "#C8C8A9"];
var _colors = ["#FE4365", "#83AF9B"]
var _generateItem = function(){
  return {
    id: Math.random(),
    name: _.sample(_names),
    bgcolor: _.sample(_bgcolors),
    color: _.sample(_colors),
   // opacity: new Transitionable(0),
  //  transX: new Transitionable(-_width)
  }
}
//why is _.range needed? why just make STARTING_NUMBER = [0];
$scope.items = _.map(_.range(STARTING_NUMBER), function(){
      return _generateItem();
    })

console.log($scope.items);
```

Answer (score 1):

The range function will return an array of integers when passed a single value:

```
e.g. _.range(1) returns [0],   
     _.range(2) returns [0, 1]
```

What the code is doing is calling generateItem once when STARTING_NUMBER is 1, twice if STARTING_NUMBER is 2 etc. and adding the output of generateItem to an array.

It can be more succinctly coded as:

```
$scope.items = _.times(STARTING_NUMBER, generateItem);
```

Comment: I dont see anywhere in the code, where starting_number is increasing/decreasing :c  the example app is just creating a new object every 1second and mapping it to the items.  I think they are just trying to use a variable like range incase you wanted to add more than one every second.  Regardless your _.times has helpped me understand lo-dash more.

Comment: Sometimes capitalized variable names are used to denote constants which is what I think is going on here. There's no need to use range though as the values in the array returned by range are not passed to the generateItem function.